# Why can't I change the target framework to 4.5 in Windows 8, using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, .net-framework-version

When I try to change it to 4.5, I only see 4.5.1.

[image]

When I try to install 4.5, from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653), I get the following message:

[image]

So, it's already apart of the OS, but I can't select it in VS2012.

Any ideas?

Comment: it says same or higher version, that's why you cannot install 4.5. Anyway, what do you need 4.5 as target platform for?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project(s)/solution?

Comment: `4.5.1` _is_ `4.5`. In fact, it's .1 better.

Comment: @David I'm working in two different environments. One of which doesn't have 4.5. I thought 4.5.1 was exclusive to Windows 8. I'll just have to update the other environment to 4.5.1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.5.1 IS .NET 4.5

Microsoft fixed a few things and added a few new features and pushed the update out.  You CANNOT downgrade from 4.5.1 to 4.5.

Here is the article from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#v451

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it. I'm working on it in two different environments. One of which doesn't have 4.5.1. I'll have to update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.NET `4.5.1` *is* `4.5`:

> The .NET Framework 4.5.1 is an in-place update to the .NET Framework 4.5.

Also, `4.5` replaces `4`:

> The .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Framework 4.5.1 replace the .NET Framework 4. When you install these versions on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx